# how to access resources which are available in tomcat folder using java webapplication?

Tags: java, servlets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Configure Tomcat to use properties file to load DB connection information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380793/configure-tomcat-to-use-properties-file-to-load-db-connection-information)

I would like to set some values in properties file and put the file in somewhere in tomcat because the property file's values are changeable. I will give only war file and properties file the customer will change values in properties file while using the application.

```
mail.smtp.host=smtp.gmail.com
mail.smtp.port= 465
```

This is what is my exact need. I want to set the values for this `mail.smtp.host` and `mail.smtp.port`

I want to access these values from servlet.

please help me how to go about.

Regards
Tony

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
servletContext.getRealPath("/");
```

and then you can navigate to your directory from tomcat

**Also See**

- [properties file in web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814506/properties-file-in-web-app)

Comment: servletContext can not be resolved. error

Comment: from servlet you from service method you need to do `getServletContext()` that will return ` servletContext`