# Getting Properties Object from config.properties file after deployment

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web, properties, config

I have a config file containing server information such as FTP URL's and their credentials. I am trying to, on deployment of my web app, reference the config.properties file to assign the stored values to local variables but for whatever reason cannot find the file.

I have a getConfigProperties class:

```
public class getConfigProperties {

public Properties getConfig(String fileName) {
    // load config file
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream input = null;

    try {
        // grab config file from destination
        input = getConfigProperties.class.getClass().getResourceAsStream(
                fileName);
        // check if input is null
        if (input == null) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, unable to find "
                    + "config.properties");
            return null;
        }
        // load content
        prop.load(input);

        // start to declare variables
        // Prod vars
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("prismUrlProd"));
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("prismUserProd"));
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("prismPassProd"));
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("cardUrlProd"));
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("cardUserProd"));
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("cardPassProd"));
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("pwcProd"));
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("esdSignInProd"));
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("emailProd"));

        // used to catch possible errors
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (input != null) {
            try {
                input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return prop;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    getConfigProperties a = new getConfigProperties();
    a.getConfig("/config/config.properties");
}
}
```

And I use this in another class to assign the variables. Inside my method, I set a Properties object to what is returned from getConfig(String filename):

```
public static void initialize() {
    // load config file
    getConfigProperties config = new getConfigProperties();
    Properties prop = config.getConfig("/config/config.properties");
}
```

It's explained in [properties file in web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814506/properties-file-in-web-app) that on deplyoment, our location of the config.properties changes, but when trying "/WEB-INF/classes/config/config.properties", I can't find the file. Using the main in my getConfigProperties class, I am able to find config.properties no problem and reference the text in my config file by printing it to console. Any possible suggestions as to where this file may be on deployment? Do I have to reference it a certain way? Any help would much be appreciated.

Comment: I was able to get this working on deployment, but only when I had my config.properties file in the src folder. I referenced the file using just "config.properties" as my file path. Even though this works, I was hoping I could somehow reference it in a package for organization purposes. This will have to do for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work by putting config.properties in my src folder and referencing it by "config.properties".